# Technical reason of data loss of variable

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer.

A Polymer component is bound to a script which handles its logic. It looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-component">

  <template></template>

  <script src="my-component.js"></script>

</polymer-element>
```

The component is generated by passing an object to the `Polymer` function. This object describes the component and must contain at least a property named `ready`. This is a function that fires everytime the component is generated, e.g when the script is called the very first time & every time it is used after that initial call.

This is my `my-component.js`

```
var Timeline;

function loadTimeline(){
  return System.import('balance/timeline/TimeLineModule')
    .then(function(TM){
       Timeline = TM.service;
     });
 };

loadTimeline()
 .then(function(){

     var element = (function

     var component;

     return{
        ready: function(){
          var self = this;
          component = this;
          methodThatUtilizesTimelineModule();
        }
     }

})();

  Polymer('day-view',element);

})
.catch(function(e){console.error(e)});
```

My Problem now, is that everything works fine as long the script is called for the first time. Howevery, as soon as I leave the component and call another one, then return to the one that belongs to the script above, `Timeline` will be `undefined` and can only be used again if I call `loadTimeline()` again from somewhere within the component object.

So I know that the issue is that the value of my variable get's lost whenever I leave the component that calls that script, but I don't know why this is.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Polymer, but perhaps you could use globals?

```
<polymer-element name="app-globals">
  <script>
  (function() {
    // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
    var firstName = 'John';
    var lastName = 'Smith';

    Polymer({
       ready: function() {
         // copy global values into instance properties
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
       }
    });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then use it like this

```
<polymer-element name="my-component">
  <template>
    <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
    <div id="firstname">{{$.globals.firstName}}</div>
    <div id="lastname">{{$.globals.lastName}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        console.log('Last name: ' + this.$.globals.lastName);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

See the API developer guide on [polymer-project](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html)

Comment: Thank you. I am sure this would work quite good, but I just don't like to have to include an elmeent to my markup to gain access to a service. It feels wrong to me. I know this is what Polymer advises to do, though.